# Can I create a vector with regexps?

Tags: r, regex, vector

My data looks somthing like this:

```
412 U CA, Riverside
413 U British Columbia
414 CREI
415 U Pompeu Fabra
416 Office of the Comptroller of the Currency, US Department of the Treasury
417 Bureau of Economics, US Federal Trade Commission
418 U Carlos III de Madrid
419 U Brescia
420 LUISS Guido Carli
421 U Alicante
422 Harvard Society of Fellows
423 Toulouse School of Economics
424 Decision Economics Inc, Boston, MA
425 ECARES, Free U Brussels
```

I will need to geocode this data in order to get the coordinates for each specific institution. in order to do that I need all state names to be spelled out. At the same time I don't want acronyms like "ECARES" to be transformed into "ECaliforniaRES".

I have been toying with the idea of converting the state.abb and state.name vectors into vectors of regular expressions, so that state.abb would look something like this (Using Alabama and California as state 1 and state 2):

```
c("^AL "|" AL "|" AL,"|",AL "| " AL$", "^CA "[....])
```

And the state.name vector something like this:

```
c("^Alabama "|" Alabama "|" Alabama,"|",Alabama "| " Alabama$", "^California "[....])
```

Hopefully, I can then use the mgsub function to replace all expressions in the modified state.abb vector with the corresponding entries in the modified state.name vector.

For some reason, however, it doesn't seem to be possible to put regexps in a vector:

```
    test<-c(^AL, ^AB)
Error: unexpected '^' in "test<-c(^"
```

I have tried excusing the "^"-signs but this doesnt really seem to work:

```
test<-c(\^AL, \^AB)
Error: unexpected input in "test<-c(\"
> test<-c(\\^AL, \\^AB)
```

Is there any way of putting regexps in a vector, or is there another way of achieving my goal (that is, to replace all two-letter state abbreviations to state names without messing up other acronyms in the process)?

Excerpt of my data:

```
c("U Lausanne", "Swiss Finance Institute", "U CA, Riverside", 
"U British Columbia", "CREI", "U Pompeu Fabra", "Office of the Comptroller of the Currency, US Department of the Treasury", 
"Bureau of Economics, US Federal Trade Commission", "U Carlos III de Madrid", 
"U Brescia", "LUISS Guido Carli", "U Alicante", "Harvard Society of Fellows", 
"Toulouse School of Economics", "Decision Economics Inc, Boston, MA", 
"ECARES, Free U Brussels", "Baylor U", "Research Centre for Education", 
"the Labour Market, Maastricht U", "U Bonn", "Swarthmore College"
)
```

Comment: You can find all 2-letter abbreviations with `[^a-zA-Z]([A-Z]{2})[^a-zA-Z]` and you will need to make use of `$1`. As for translating them into their full state name you will need programming logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can make use of the `state.abb` `vector` and `paste` it together by `collapse`ing with `|`

```
pat1 <- paste0("\\b(", paste(state.abb, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
```

The `\\b` signifies the word boundary so that indiscriminate matches "SAL" can be avoided

and similarly with `state.name`, `paste` the `^` and `$` as prefix/suffix to mark the start, end of the string respectively

```
pat2 <- paste0("^(", paste(state.name, collapse="|"), ")$")
```

Comment: Okay I think I get the gist of it , but why is the first word boundry expressed with one backslash and the second one with two?

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to function with gsub or mgsub :/

Comment: @Magnus  If you want to do this separately, then don't collapse it.  but paste the `\\b` separately.  I was thinking that you wanted to `grep` at once

Comment: So something like:

pat1 <- paste0("\b(", paste(state.abb), ")\\b")
> pat2 <- paste0("^(", paste(state.name), ")$")
> df[]<-mgsub(pat1, pat2, as.matrix(df))

?

Comment: @Magnus there is a `mgsub` package and also another one in `qdap` Not sure which one you are ussing

Comment: I'm using the one from qdap, should I use the one from the package?

Comment: @Magnus with `mgsub::mgsub` `mgsub("AL is the best",  c("\\bAL\\b", "\\bAL\\b"), c("Alabama", "Alaska"))# [1] "Alabama is the best"`

Comment: @Magnus if you are patterns `pat1 <- paste0("\\b", state.abb, "\\b");mgsub('AL is the best', pat1, state.name)#
[1] "Alabama is the best"`

Comment: Okay, I had to replace pat2 with just the state.name vector since I got entries like ^(California)$ but other than that this seems to work.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Magnus In the replacement, if you add `^$`, it would replace that literally.  I was under the assumption that this was another set of patterns